# Gray dot on google maps android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I'm trying to set the emulator location but I always get that gray dot instead of the blue dot.
[image]

not only that but when I try to get navigation direction I got this error.

> Can't connect to google maps Try again in few minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you see a grey dot for your current location, it means that the location is loading. Once it loads all its location detecting methods you enabled (GPS, Mobile network etc) and the location has been detected, it will turn to blue.

Comment: the problem is it never turns to blue.

by the way, the problem has been solved now for some unknown reason. after updating the emulator and using API versions.